# Php loop not showing me result of operation but no errors

Tags: php

```
for ($i= count($words); $i < count($words) -1 ; $i++) { 
                       $w = strtolower(array_values($words)[$i]);
                       $s = array_map('strtolower',$string_to_search);
                       if (in_array($s , $w)) {
                           echo $w;
                           echo "im here";
                       }
                    }
```

1. The code above is supposed to check if a word is in an array and if so count it. Im not getting errors but I cant see results please help
2. Ive tried the foreach loop but its not working aswell
   **Can someone please tell me where im messing up im a noob in php**

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Your for loop doesn't even go through once! If you do this: `for ($i= count($words); $i < count($words) -1 ; $i++)` it's like this: `for ($i= 5; 5 < 4 ; $i++)` <- The condition is from the start false! (Wait until all vampires come and you will get your answer)

Comment: Now after the edit period  of 5min I will also add here that you still won't run through your entire array, even if you do all changes from the answers down below! Because you subtract 1 from your count and use `<`! So either change `<` to `<=` or don't subtract 1 from your count!

Answer (score 2):

start this loop with `for ($i = 0;` because when you start from count, it is not iterating at all:

```
for ($i= 0; $i <= count($words) -1 ; $i++) {
```

Comment: Should I ask now if you stared 13min at OP's code until you spotted the missing equal sign(`<=`)?

Comment: @Rizier123 I knew it from the beginning but didn't bother to check why it is iterated to last but one, I assumed it was on purpose and thought the most relevant was this 0. After your remark I changed that, forgot to say thank you for further investigation, I had urgency somewhere else, sorry, it won't happen

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to be as follows:

```
for ($i= 0; $i < count($words) -1 ; $i++) { 
                   $w = strtolower(array_values($words)[$i]);
                   $s = array_map('strtolower',$string_to_search);
                   if (in_array($s , $w)) {
                       echo $w;
                       echo "im here";
                   }
                }
```